# Why is my text not changing as I'm writing text to the input tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

My code from App.js. The idea is that when you enter text in input the screen should be updated accordingly. For some reason set state isn't working and I don't know why.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserOutput from './Components/UserOutput';
import UserInput from './Components/UserInput';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    username: 'Adib',
  };
  changeUsername = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserInput changed={this.changeUsername} />
        <UserOutput name={this.state.username} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My code from useroutput.js

```
import React from 'react';

const userOutput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Username: {props.name}</p>
      <p>Hello {props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default userOutput;
```

My code from userinput.js

```
import React from 'react';

const userInput = (props) => {
  return <input type="text" onChanged={props.changed} />;
};

export default userInput;
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML from when you load the page?

Comment: `onChanged` needs to be `onChange`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `onChanged` as the name of the event action on the input field in the `userInput` Component. replace it with

```
return <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserInput` component is using an `onChanged` event which is not a valid event in React, try using `onChange` instead.

```
import React from 'react';

const userInput = (props) => {
  return <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} />;
};

export default userInput;
```